# How do I disable filp/whoops package in Laravel 5.5 without removing it?

Tags: php, composer-php, homestead, laravel-5.5, whoops

Laravel 5.5 app. Originally 5.3. I installed the `filp/whoops` package as per the upgrade guide, but now I want to disable it, as I believe it is causing "out of memory" errors on my Homestead machine whenever I encounter an error, which is really annoying because all I see is "allowed memory size of XXXXXX bytes exhausted" instead of the real error, which is usually a parse error of some sort. I do NOT want to change the memory available to PHP as it matches what I have on my production server.

Is there any simple way to disable this package without removing it?

Comment: It's unlikely that Whoops is causing the out-of-memory errors, as it's not loaded or executed until an actual error is encountered.

Comment: Beside this, the Woops package is not activated on production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add into `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` the following method:

```
protected function renderExceptionWithWhoops(Exception $e)
{
    return $this->renderExceptionWithSymfony($e, config('app.debug'));
}
```

This will override default implementation and should cause rendering exception without Whoops package.

Comment: Thanks! Sadly this did not solve my out of memory issue, but it appears to have worked for disabling Whoops.

Comment: Shooting the messenger is never a good idea. Increase you memory limit on your local machine and let woops do its job - telling you what kind of error you have and fix this.